Change YSQL in YugabyteDB to scroll horizontally?
Is it possible to change ysqlsh to scroll horizontally instead of wrap long tables and be able to use PgUp and PgDn similar to psql?
I can't find it in the docs.

ysqlsh and psql are very similar but we compile with a different GLIBC.
Ok, I get the same. Works when passed in command line but not with interactive.
In the meantime, workaround is ysql --no-readline. You can install rlwrap to get command history. Or install psql. Or connect from outside of the container with any PostgreSQL client

